# Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(GoogleApiClient, PutDataRequest) leaks when used in working thread

Tags: android, multithreading, memory-leaks, google-api, wear-os

I am using a task that is repeatedly executed to sync data between my wearable and my handheld. Therefore a service is started that starts postDelayed a Runnable. In its run() method a PutDataRequest is created and send via

```
 Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(googleApiClient, putDataRequest);
```

after that a new run of that task is schedulead via postDelayed() method.

That all works fine, however, the line:

```
 Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(googleApiClient, putDataRequest);
```

somehow leaks and therefore after some time the app crashes. Does anyone know why? Or is that a bug of the Api?

My code of the Runnable is as follows:

```
  private static class WeakRunnable implements Runnable{
    private WeakReference<WearManagerWearable> weakWearManager;
    private WeakReference<HashMap<Integer,MySensorEventListeners>> weakListenerList;
    private WeakReference<Handler> weakHandler;

   protected WeakRunnable(WearManagerWearable wearManager, HashMap<Integer,MySensorEventListeners> listenerList , Handler handler ){
        weakWearManager = new WeakReference<>(wearManager);
        weakListenerList = new WeakReference<>(listenerList);
        weakHandler = new WeakReference<>(handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        WearManagerWearable wearManager = weakWearManager.get();
        GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = wearManager.googleApiClient;
        HashMap<Integer,MySensorEventListeners> listenerList = weakListenerList.get();
        if(wearManager.isApiConnected()) {
            ArrayList<DataMap> dataMapArrayList = new ArrayList<DataMap>();
            for (MySensorEventListeners listener : listenerList.values()) {
                DataMap dataMap = new DataMap();
                dataMap.putString("Name" , listener.getName() );
                dataMap.putInt("Type" , listener.getType());
                dataMap.putFloatArray("Data" , listener.getData());
                dataMapArrayList.add(dataMap);
            }
            PutDataMapRequest putDataMapRequest = PutDataMapRequest.create("/sensorData");
            putDataMapRequest.getDataMap().putDataMapArrayList("DataMapList", dataMapArrayList);
            PutDataRequest putDataRequest = putDataMapRequest.asPutDataRequest();
            //send
            Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(googleApiClient, putDataRequest); // this line leaks (when commented out no leaks)
            Log.d("Wearable", "Data sending");
        }

        Handler handler = weakHandler.get();
        handler.postDelayed(this, updateTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you think it leaks ?

Comment: I analysed it with the Android Studio memory analyser. The heap is growing with time and the GC does not clean the allocated memory anymore. Then I tracked it down until that line, that when I comment it out no leaks occure.

Comment: When using a weak reference, you should be checking to see if your reference is null. After your app has been running for a while, weakWearManager.get() could return null. Do you have a stack trace at the time the app crashes?